# Add local CSS to Domain Online UIWebView

Tags: ios, css, objective-c, uiwebview

Hi I wan't to add css styles to a `UIWebView`

***CSS Code***

```
<style>body{ background: none; } .sepLine{ display: none; } .wrapper{ width: 320px; }</style>
```

***Code for UIWebView***

```
NSString *fullURL = @"http://parentportal.npsinternational.edu.sg/nps/Dashboard.aspx";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

How do I do this

Answer (score 0):

Use the UIWebView delegate method `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` to wait for the page to finish loading then inject the CSS using JavaScript with `- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to load HTML string, append styles and than load it to web view.
Try this code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://parentportal.npsinternational.edu.sg/nps/Dashboard.aspx";
    NSString *style = @"<style> ... </style>";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];

    NSError* error = nil;

    //load HTML string
    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if(!error){
        //append style string
        html = [html stringByAppendingString:style];

        //load webview
        [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:url];
    }
});
```

It is only example, you'd better to load string with advanced network tool, e.g [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)